# Create x number of new cells based on a number in a different cell

Tags: google-sheets-formula

The Short Ask:

Given a cell (C2) with a number, say 9, how can I create 9 new cells starting in A8 where I use the url in A2 but add "/season/1" and then "/season/2" right up to season 9, and then repeat for the urls in A3 to A6, given their respective season numbers in C3 to C9?

Context:

Cell A2 has a url to a tv show, and cell C2 has a number of seasons.
Cell A3 has a url to a tv show, and cell C3 has a number of seasons.
I do this for 5 rows (A2 to C6)

I use a script to get info from these urls.

But now I need to generate more urls to get another script to give me info about each episode. Basically I need one url per show, per season.

My spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eNMuQVp0ghiAhsKGaOMjtzFmaPuTKCH57tSfXgql1SE/edit?usp=sharing

Updated (again) to include proper link to spreadsheet

Comment: Please give access to linked spreadsheet.

Comment: I'm so sorry.  I use this same spreadsheet for all of my requests here and it's always been set to "shared with link", until now.  It's here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eNMuQVp0ghiAhsKGaOMjtzFmaPuTKCH57tSfXgql1SE/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in A8:

```
=query(flatten(transpose(ifna(ArrayFormula(iferror(transpose(split(rept(A2:A7&"season/^",C2:C7),"^")))&int(SEQUENCE(100,100,0,1)/100+1))))),"select * where Col1 contains '.'",0)
```

This is a quite long formula as Google Sheets do not provide loops. Here I make an array of urls, then combine them with a grid of numbers 100 by 100. Then I combine those 2 grids, flatten them and remove numbers that I don't need.

If you are interested I can elaborate more about this formula.

Limitations:

Each url has to contain .

Maximum number of seasons is 100.

Url cannot contain ^

[image: Screenshot of my solution]

Working spreadsheet here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YevtYcG-EiVuW60kH-UDVgSObx-cp9JvgJ56o68s_0c/copy

Comment: Complex, but I think I can see what's going on. I did't know about REPT and SEQUENCE - those are amazing functions. I'll tear it apart and recreate until I know exactly what's going on  and if I have a question, I'll ask here. Thank you!